# How to access Edit functionality in new Photos application?

Tags: macos, applications, photos.app

In OS X Yosemite (update 10.10.3), there is the new photos application. I am unable to access the edit function when I use this application.

Answer (score 1):

Image Menu > Show Image tools

or just select a photo & hit  <kbd>Return⏎</kbd>